# Installing Windows 8 on late 2012 iMac 3TB SATA Disk

Tags: partitioning, bios, sata, boot-camp, imac

Yes I know installing windows on the new 3TB iMac through bootcamp is not officially supported, but after doing some research it seemed that it was quite possible to do so anyways. Twocanoes seemed to have the best solution for going about this so I gave it a try

http://blog.twocanoes.com/post/42453643591/bootcamp-on-a-3-tb-fusion-drive

I seem to have run into a problem at the very last step. I successfully created the partitions as above, created a bootable usb with bootcamp on a different mac, and then when I go to select what drive to boot from, my bootable usb shows two different drive options (Windows and EFI). If I select Windows, I can successfully install it on to my partition, but no compatibility drivers seem to be installed with it (internet, graphics, bluetooth). If I boot from the EFI option, I make it to the windows installer, but then receive an error telling me:

"The selected disk has an MBR partition table. On EFI systems, Windows can only be installed to GPT disks. Windows cannot be installed to this disk. This computer's hardware may not support booting to this disk. Ensure that the disk controller is enabled in the computer's BIOS menu."

Any help on what I am doing wrong or what I might try will be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: Here is what Apple told me about this situation if anyone is interested: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4856879

Comment: Update: This solved my problem: http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p682/download-bootcamp-drivers